# Change tty respawn in Debian 9 (Stretch )

Tags: debian, login, tty, getty

I try to change respawn tty to some other bin file , before that I configure that on /etc/inittab 
But now this file doesn’t exist ; how can I do that ?
( my goal is “ call my binary instead of tty ” )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/etc/inittab` is the configuration file of classic SysVinit. Debian 9 uses `systemd` instead by default, although I think you still have an option to use another init system if you wish.

With `systemd`, the `getty` processes (= those responsible for handling login prompts on TTY devices) are managed by `getty@.service` which is defined by file `/lib/systemd/system/getty@.service`. If you want to modify it, you can either use `systemctl edit getty@.service` to automatically create a partial override file, or copy the file from `/lib/systemd/system/` directory to `/etc/systemd/system` and then modify it; a customized file in `/etc/systemd/system` will override a standard file with the same name at `/lib/systemd/system`.

You should not modify any of the files in `/lib/systemd`: if you do, your changes may be overwritten in the next `systemd` update. Instead make your changes and additions in `/etc/systemd/`: that's what it's for.

Comment: You can also use `systemctl edit --full` to copy the unit file in its entirety and edit it.